# Sql select multiple values from another query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have three tables in php-mysql
**products,product_fact,fact**
schema is like this

**products**

```
 id , name (1000 records)
```

Eg-

```
id     |    name
-------+--------
1125   | key chain
1135   | bikes
1145   | cars
```

**id** = has different id numbers of the products every product has a unique id,

**name** = name of products

**product_fact**

```
product_id, fact_id
```

**product_id** = this is the same **id** that is in products table

**fact_id** = this is fact id every products have some facts, many of the products has more than one fact.

Eg-

```
product_id  |  fact_id
------------+----------
1125        |      5
1125        |      7
1125        |      6
1135        |      8
1145        |      9
1145        |      2
```

**fact**

```
id , name
```

**id** = this is fact_id same as in table product_fact

**name** = this is the name of fact.

Eg-

```
id      |    name
--------+---------
 2      |   black
 8      |   free
 5      |   sold
 6      |   coming soon
 9      |   new
```

Now i want to select particular fact name related to the product, but when i execute this query -->

```
SELECT name
FROM fact
Where id = (SELECT fact_id
FROM product_fact
Where product_id='1125');
```

It says **Subquery returns more than 1 row**

But when i run this query -->

```
SELECT name
FROM fact
Where id = (SELECT fact_id
FROM product_fact
Where product_id='1135');
```

It gives me correct output : **free**

What should i do now it should display fact name's for other products any help,
what else should i have to include in my query.. any help

Answer (score 14, accepted):

to be more safe with subquery, use `IN` instead of `=`

```
SELECT name 
FROM   fact 
Where id IN (SELECT fact_id 
             FROM   product_fact 
             WHERE  product_id='1125');
```

or using `JOIN`

```
SELECT  DISTINCT a.name
FROM    fact a
        INNER JOIN product_fact b
            ON a.ID = b.fact_ID
WHERE   b.product_ID = '1125'
```